# Is this ternary safely handling undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

is the following snippet safe?

```
function theFunc(arg1, optionalList) {
   optionalList = optionalList ? optionalList : [];
   //do stuff with arg1 and optionalList
}
```

I added the ternary to handle the case where `optionalList` is not provided (previously complaining about being undefined) and a coworker pointed out it's not the accepted way to test for undefined.

It makes sense to me, because undefined should be falsey, but I can see examples online of people saying to always use `typeof`. I've tried it across Chrome, FF and Edge and it seems to be okay. Is there some reason to not use this method to default an optional to an empty list?
n.b I'm supporting IE and cannot use default in the args list.

Comment: Do you mean to use `(arg1, arg2)` in the argument list?

Comment: depends ... what other possible values can arg2 have? any of them falsey?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: The key issue with this ternary is that it will evaluate anything that is "falsey" to the second value. Means, if you provide an array, it should be no issue. But if, for example, you use this for number type values, it can have annoying side effects.

Comment: where is `arg2` supposed to come from, is that a global one?

Comment: My mistake, arg2 should have been optionalList.

Comment: If you do expect `optionalList` to be an Array, as your setting of the default value suggests, then you'd probably be better doing `if( !Array.isArray( optionalList ) ) { optionalList = []; }`. Point being, the safeness of this code really depends on what it should prevent/ensure.

Comment: @Kaiido thank you, this is probably a good way to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if `arg2` is falsey but not undefined (eg, 0, or the empty string, or NaN, or null), your logic will change it to `[]`. If your `arg2` has a chance of holding a meaningful falsey value, you should change your code to

```
arg2 = typeof arg2 === 'undefined' ? [] : arg2
```

otherwise, non-undefined falsey values will be discarded and replaced with `[]`.

If you're not worried about `undefined` being a variable name currently in scope, that simplifies to:

```
arg2 = arg2 === undefined ? [] : arg2
```

If `arg2` *will* always be truthy, if defined, then your current code is fine, for the most part (but make sure to always use the variable name `arg2`, or `optionalList`, but don't mix them).

I'd still prefer to use default arguments:

```
function theFunc(arg1, arg2 = []) {
```

ES6+ syntax allows for *many* sorts of nice and concise codes which aren't possible in ES5. For any reasonably sized or professional script, it's probably a better idea to set up Babel to transpile your code to ES5 automatically, allowing you to write in the latest and greatest version of the language, rather than cripple the readability of your code by forcing yourself to only use obsolete syntax.

Comment: Maybe as one additional improvement idea: Also check for "arg2 === null".

Answer (score 1):

Your coworker was probably talking about:

```
function theFunc(arg1, optionalList) {
   optionalList = optionalList || [];
   //do stuff with arg1 and optionalList
}
```

This is the usual way of having default values for arguments in JavaScript. It should be safe here if `optionalList` can only be a list.

Answer (score 1):

An example is better than a long speech

```js
function ES_5_Func(arg1, optionalList)
  {
  optionalList = optionalList || [];    // es5 classic method
  console.log( arg1, JSON.stringify( optionalList ))
  }

function ES_6_Func(arg1, optionalList = []) // es6 method for default value
  {
  console.log( arg1, JSON.stringify( optionalList ))
  }


ES_5_Func('test 1arg ES 5')                // --> test 1arg ES 5 []  
ES_5_Func('test 2args ES 5', ['hello 5'])   // --> test 2args ES 5 ["hello 5"]

ES_6_Func('test 1arg ES 6')                // --> test 1arg ES 6 [] 
ES_6_Func('test 2args ES 6', ['hello 6'])   // --> test 2args ES 6 ["hello 6"]
```